# Style inheritance issue mixing types

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to **factorize** some styles with common properties.

So I'm using style inheritance but seems like it's not fully implemented.

Say I have these two styles:

```
<Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is my first try:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
</Style>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" TargetType="ProgressBar"></Style>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" TargetType="Rectangle"></Style>
```

It's running but the Visual Studio designer is not happy and it displays this error:

```
Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type of this style's target type.
```

AFAIK if I trust MSDN both `ProgressBar` and `Rectangle` should inherit from `FrameworkElement`.

Here is the full code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <!--<Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
        </Style>-->
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" TargetType="ProgressBar"></Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" TargetType="Rectangle"></Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ProgressBar Value="50"></ProgressBar>
    <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True"></ProgressBar>
    <Rectangle Width="100" Fill="BlueViolet"></Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```

Note that the exact same code is working fine with WPF both in the designer and at runtime.

Is this a VS bug or a WinRT limitation?

Am I doing something wrong?